# ETH transfer help

Tags: tokens, exchanges

Hi I have opened my first coin wallet - metamask.

I have bought ETH through here and now tried to send to Binance to buy BAT.

I just wondered how long it usually takes to transfer ETH as it seems to be taking a long time.

How do I see how many confirmations the transaction has?

If anyone can point me in the direction of some useful documents to read to gain a good understanding of how the entire toke trading economy works that would be great, ie gas whats this for, how transferring across the blockchain works etc. Should have done some reading first I guess but just jumped in.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  "Should have done some reading first I guess but just jumped in." Yes you should :)

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes to transfer ETH is not precise, since it changes according to the network congestion. If it is taking too long I suggest you try the same transaction again, but this time with a higher gas price.

Click on Metamask icon, then click on the transaction that is taking too long (sent tab) it should take you to etherscan, where you can check how many confirmations it has and other stuff.